# Firestore timestamp getting null

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using firestore in my android project, everything working fine.But Yesterday an issue occurred on getting timestamp value from document snapshot.

```
if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) { 
  Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap = documentChange.getDocument().getData(); 
  Date date = (Date) stringObjectMap.get("timestamp"); }
```

This is one of my Collection Document.

```
 id : "25",
 message : "This is my message",
 timestamp : December 11, 2017 at 10:39:12 PM UTC+5, \\This is Firebase FieldValue.serverTimestamp()
 username : "Temp"
```

I get everything from the document except for timestamp.

Comment: If you're getting null, perhaps try parsing it as a String value. If not try `HashMap<String, String>`. I usually save my timestamps as Unix Timestamps to ensure they can be encoded by any platform I use. Try provide more code for the error

Comment: I'm already parsing it with HashMap<String,Object>.@martinomburajr

Comment: Can you share part of the code where you are extracting the data ?

Comment: `if (documentChange.getType() == DocumentChange.Type.ADDED) { Map<String, Object> stringObjectMap = documentChange.getDocument().getData(); Date date = (Date) stringObjectMap.get("timestamp"); }`@2hTu2

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you are seeing this `ADDED` event with a null timestamp after writing from the same client, this is the expected behavior.

When you write with server timestamps you will get two events:

1. An initial event confirming the document write in the local cache.
    At this point the timestamp is `null` because the server has not set
    it yet.
2. A second event where the timestamp has been set by the server and
    the client has observed the change.

We are working on an API to make this behavior configurable, but right now you need to handle this case.

---

**Edit** You can now control this behavior.

```
DocumentSnapshot snap = ...

// One of ESTIMATE, NONE, or PREVIOUS
DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior behavior = ...

Date date = snap.getDate("fieldName", behavior);
```

The previous behavior (returning `null` when not known) is equivalent to `NONE` in the new API.  For more information, see the JavaDoc:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot.ServerTimestampBehavior

Comment: This is difficult to work around and I hope you address this soon.

Comment: I can confirm, this is really difficult to work around. There should be an option to get data directly from server, not cache.